# Save with phpexcel to temporary file

Tags: php, excel, phpexcel

I have to save an excel in a temporary file but I do not know how

Originally this way I keep the excel file

```
header('Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="Autolarte.xlsx"');
header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');
header('Cache-Control: max-age=1');
header ('Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT');
header ('Last-Modified: '.gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s').' GMT'); 
header ('Cache-Control: cache, must-revalidate'); 
header ('Pragma: public'); 
$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel2007');
$objWriter->save('php://output');
```

Now what I want is to create a temporary file with the contents of that excel file

I have this example but since it is not implemented in my example since I do not know what variable is the content of my excel

```
$temp = tmpfile();
fwrite($temp, "writing in the temporary file");
fseek($temp, 0);
echo fread($temp, 1024);
fclose($temp);
```

And now it is for what I need my temporary file, I want to put the path and the name of the temporary file in addfile to add that excel to a zip

```
$zipname = 'file.zip';
$zip = new ZipArchive;
$zip->open($zipname, ZipArchive::CREATE);
$zip->addFile('/path/to/index.txt', 'newname.txt');
$zip->addFromString("testfilephp.txt", "#1 This is a test string added as  testfilephp.txt.\n");
$zip->close();
header('Content-Type: application/zip');
header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename='.$zipname);
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($zipname));
readfile($zipname);
exit;
```

Answer (score 0):

The `save()` command saves to file, but you're using `php://output` as the filename right now to get direct output. Just change it.

```
$tempfile = tempnam();
$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel2007');
$objWriter->save($tempfile);
```

Dont' forget to delete the file afterwards with `unlink()`.

Comment: `Warning: strtolower() expects parameter 1 to be string, resource given in /home1/autolart/public_html/app/webroot/descargas/PHPExcel-1.8/Classes/PHPExcel/Writer/Excel2007.php on line 189`

Comment: `Warning: file_exists() expects parameter 1 to be a valid path, resource given in /home1/autolart/public_html/app/webroot/descargas/PHPExcel-1.8/Classes/PHPExcel/Writer/Excel2007.php on line 228`

Comment: `Warning: ZipArchive::open() expects parameter 1 to be a valid path, resource given in /home1/autolart/public_html/app/webroot/descargas/PHPExcel-1.8/Classes/PHPExcel/Writer/Excel2007.php on line 232`

Comment: `Warning: ZipArchive::open() expects parameter 1 to be a valid path, resource given in /home1/autolart/public_html/app/webroot/descargas/PHPExcel-1.8/Classes/PHPExcel/Writer/Excel2007.php on line 233`

Comment: The message is from the library and this is shown when there is a misuse of the functions

Comment: One of those errors was because I used `tmpfile()` instead of `tempnam()`. Answer is edited now.

Comment: Does this store to random access memory like `php://temp`?

Comment: @CardinalSystem no it saves it to a temp file

Answer (score 0):

```
   //create a dir temporal
        $tmpHandle = tmpfile();
        $metaDatas = stream_get_meta_data($tmpHandle);
        $tmpFilename = $metaDatas['uri'];
   //create a object tu save de excel file
        $objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel2007');
   //save the excel in a temporaly dir
        $objWriter->save($tmpFilename);
   //create the zip
        $zipname = 'file.zip';
        $zip = new ZipArchive;
        $zip->open($zipname, ZipArchive::CREATE);
        $zip->addFile($tmpFilename, 'newname.xlsx');
        $zip->close();
        unlink($tmpFilename);
        fclose($tmpHandle);
        header('Content-Type: application/zip');
        header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename='.$zipname);
        header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($zipname));
        readfile($zipname);
        exit;
```